# What does it mean for a Hermitian sesquilinear form to be 'anisotropic'?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, sesquilinear-forms

I've seen some references to a 'Hermitian and anisotropic sesquilinear form' with no definition of anisotropy given. According to this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_quadratic_form), a quadratic form is *anisotropic* if $q(v)=0\Longrightarrow v=0$, but I have not seen a similar definition for sesquilinear forms. I would have thought it might be $h(x,x)=0\Longrightarrow x=0$ like with inner products, but this is just a guess.

Is there a standard definition of isotropy/anisotropy in this context?

EDIT: The main reference I am referring to is Definition 2.1 of [this paper](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc9204/alva.pdf).

Comment: @hardmath The Wikipedia page does define what an anisotropic quadratic form means, and they have correctly paraphrased the definition as "$q(v) = 0 \implies v = 0$."

Comment: @hardmath I have added a reference to my question that refers to a 'Hermitian and anisotropic sesquilinear form' without stating what anisotropic means.

Comment: There is a definition of isotropy/anisotropy for bilinear forms in [this PDF](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/LieClifford/cl12.pdf) which seems to suggest that your guess for the definition of "anistropic sesquilinear form" is correct. (But I am not an expert on this.)

Comment: @hardmath It gives a definition of a totally isotropic subspace, but still no definition of what is means for an actual sesquilinear form to be isotropic/anisotropic. Besides, the Wikipedia article I referenced defines isotropic subspaces in relation to quadratic forms, but still gives a definition of being isotropic without mentioning subspaces.